# How to place buttons in a very specific place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want the buttons to be placed using something like coordinates. I've tried using pack and grid. I want to be able to like skip columns if using grid or determine the size of each column/row. Every time the number adds an extra digit it pushes the buttons over and makes it look weird. Is there anyway to avoid this? If there is a way to continue using grid or pack and fix my problem how would I do it?

```
#Date: November 25, 2015
#FIle: TestingStatsGUI.py

import tkinter as tk

class PickStats(tk.Frame):
    health_attr = 0
    health = 90
    energy = 45
    energy_attr = 0
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="Black")
        tk.activeforeground= "blak"
        master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Player")
        root.geometry("850x550")
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=1)


        self.update_window()

    def update_window(self):
        self.healthAdd = tk.Button(self, text="+", font= 13, fg='white', bg='#000080',
                                   width = 2,
                                   command=lambda: self.update("addHealth"))
        self.healthSub = tk.Button(self, text="--", font=13, fg='white', bg='red',
                                   width = 2,
                                   command=lambda: self.update("subHealth"))
        self.HealthTotal = tk.Label(self, text="Health: {}".format(self.health),
                                   font=15, fg='#01ffff', bg='black')
        self.healthAdd.config(height = 0)
        self.HealthTotal.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
        self.healthAdd.grid(row=1, column=10, padx=6)
        self.healthSub.grid(row=1, column=20)


    def update(self, method):
        if method == "addHealth":
            self.health_attr += 1
        elif method == "subHealth":
            if self.health_attr <= 0:
                pass
            else:
                self.health_attr -= 1
        self.health = 90 + self.health_attr*4
        self.update_window()
        print(self.health)


root = tk.Tk()
app = PickStats(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is creating more and more widgets with every button click, and they are all getting stacked on top of each other. You should create widgets once, and then simply change the data that is displayed on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the specific problem that the buttons get pushed over, you simply need to give the label enough room to grow. For example, all you need to do is change one line like this:

```
self.HealthTotal = tk.Label(..., width=16)
```

You have a critical bug in your code -- with every button press you're creating more and more widgets. You only need to create the widgets once. From then on you can change the displayed value with a single statement.

For example:

```
def init_window(self):
    self.master.title("Player")
    root.geometry("850x550")
    self.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

    self.healthAdd = tk.Button(self, text="+", font= 13, fg='white', bg='#000080',
                               width = 2,
                               command=lambda: self.update("addHealth"))
    self.healthSub = tk.Button(self, text="--", font=13, fg='white', bg='red',
                               width = 2,
                               command=lambda: self.update("subHealth"))
    self.HealthTotal = tk.Label(self, text="Health: {}".format(self.health),
                                font=15, fg='#01ffff', bg='black', width=16)
    self.healthAdd.config(height = 0)
    self.HealthTotal.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
    self.healthAdd.grid(row=1, column=10, padx=6)
    self.healthSub.grid(row=1, column=20)

def update_window(self):
    self.HealthTotal.configure(text="Health: {}".format(self.health))
```

By the way, rows and columns that don't contain anything are of zero width or height. It makes no sense to put things in column 10 or 20 if there isn't anything in column 1-19.

Comment: Thank you that really helps out.